# Javers with multiple EntityManagerFactory

Tags: javers

We are just getting started with JaVers in a Spring Boot application. 
This application as two EntityManagerFactory beans:

```
@Primary
@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, Environment env) {
```

And

```
@Bean(name = "secondaryEntityManagerFactory")
```

For auditing, we are just concerned with the @Primary entity manager factory.  When we start up the application, it fails on initialization because of multiple entity manager factory beans.

Is there a way to tell JaVers just to be concerned with the @Primary factory?

Thanks!

Dave

Answer (score 0):

JaVers Spring Boot starter uses EntityManagerFactory only in startup phase to determine SQL dialect. In runtime, SQL connections are obtained from the ConnectionProvider bean:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public ConnectionProvider jpaConnectionProvider() {
    return new JpaHibernateConnectionProvider();
}
```

You can override this bean with an implementation, which will provide connections to secondary database.